# How to make the hint font family is same in all device and drawable folder xml code shows black colour in tablet?

Tags: android, xml

[image]

This mobile shows normally.

[image]

but here the font design is changed in username and password.

[image]

in tab this image user name is show like black background. But i used the same code to run all device.
To make Edit Text as rectangular shape: Drawable- shape.xml code:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
       <stroke android:width="2.5dp"
               android:color="#dddddd"/>
       <corners
               android:radius="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

EditText in XML for Hint:

```
 <EditText
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:hint="@string/userhint"
          android:textSize="30sp"
          android:id="@+id/user"
          android:background="@drawable/shape"
          android:textColorHint="@color/hint"
          android:paddingLeft="20dp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />
<View
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="20dp"/>

<EditText
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:hint="@string/passwordhint"
          android:textSize="30sp"
          android:background="@drawable/shape"
          android:id="@+id/password"
          android:inputType="textPassword"
          android:textColorHint="@color/hint"
          android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
          android:paddingLeft="20dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This**

```
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
       <stroke android:width="2.5dp"
               android:color="#dddddd"/>
       <corners
               android:radius="5dp"/>

 <solid android:color="Your Editext Background color or set white"/> 
</shape>
```

**CustomEditText.java**

```
    public class CustomEditText extends EditText {

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        if(!isInEditMode())
        init(attrs);
    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        if(!isInEditMode())
        init(attrs);

    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        if(!isInEditMode())
        init(null);
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs) 
    {
        if (attrs!=null) 
        {
             TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomTextView);
             String fontName = a.getString(R.styleable.CustomTextView_fontFamily);

             if (fontName!=null) 
             {
                 Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/"+fontName);
                 setTypeface(myTypeface);
             }
             a.recycle();
        }
    }
}
```

**How to use in Xml File**

```
   <CustomEditText
                android:id="@+id/etUserName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colorHintAndTv"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorHintAndTv"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_12px"
                customfont:fontFamily="Roboto-Regular.ttf" />
```

Comment: It's working... thanks. But please help me to find the solution for hint in xml.

Comment: @RathigaJesika Always Welcome If My answer Help You than Please Accept answer and vote up

Comment: @RathigaJesika what u want to hint  like plz explaing me

Comment: the font family is automatically changed in my mobile(Image 2). how to make it like image 1's font.

Comment: @RathigaJesika you can custom font to your text.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37698674/how-to-set-custom-font-style-for-popup-menu-item/37699151#37699151

Comment: @Sohail it's not TextView. the problem is font family is changed  in hint of the EditText.

Comment: @RathigaJesika for change Editext font, u make cutomeEditext class that extend Editext class u can set cutom font in your editext but it's not complicated but it's some dificulty

Comment: @Android Geeks do you have any code to solve this problem

Comment: @RathigaJesika yes I Have

Comment: @Android Geeks could you give it to me?

Comment: still don't know to make font family is default for all device.If you get any idea let me know.@ Android Geek.